# Invalid read of size 1

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am struggling with my c programming skills. I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.
I'm basicly passing a pointer from one function call to the next function.
I cannot see what is wrong with this...???
When I use Valgrind I can't figure out what the error meens.

Here is a distilled version of my functions.

```
*/  CIcp.c   /*
153int CIcp_SetUsedIOs(CIcp this, char *str, int len, dataTypes type)
154{
155 ASSERT();
156 if(str == NULL)
157     return 0;
158 for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
159 {
160     if(str[i] > '8' || str[i] < '0')
161         continue;
162     else
163     {
164         if((type == DI) || (type == AI))
165         {
166             this->usedInputs |= (0x01 << (str[i] - '0'));
167         }
168         else
169         {
170             this->usedOutputs |= (0x01 << (str[i] - '0'));
171         }
172     }
173 }
174 log_info( "ICP %d Used input [%s]", this->id, ctob(this->usedInputs));
175 return 0;
176}

char *getvalue (CParamList This, const char *name) {
    char *result = NULL;
    pnv   currnv = This->current->nvlist;
    while (currnv)
    {
        if ((strcmp(name,currnv->name)== 0 )) /* 0 = match */
        {
            result = currnv->value;
            break;
        }
        currnv = currnv->next;
    }

    return result;
}

int LoadParams(CSdcList this)
{
    pPtN tmpThread;
    CIcp icp;

    for(int i = 0; i < this->icp->count; i++)
    {
        tmpThread = findNodeByIdx(this->icp, i);
        icp = (CIcp)tmpThread->sdc;
        if (isname(this->cPl, tmpThread->name, this->keys.ICP_DO))
        {
            char str[MAX_STR_LEN] = {0};
            CIcp_SetUsedIOs(icp, getvalue(this->cPl, this->keys.ICP_DO), MAX_STR_LEN, DO);
        }
    }
}
```

Valgrind gives me this output.
When I read the documentaion it sayes: "This happens when your program reads or writes memory at a place which Memcheck reckons it shouldn't."
But I can't see that I'm doing this...!!

```
    ==5695== Invalid read of size 1
    ==5695==    at 0x406ABF: CIcp_SetUsedIOs (CIcp.c:160)
    ==5695==    by 0x40A9E2: LoadParams (CSdcList.c:1163)
    ==5695==    by 0x407B84: getCSdcList (CSdcList.c:396)
    ==5695==    by 0x40DC5F: main (main.c:48)
    ==5695==  Address 0x5b86e0c is 0 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
    ==5695==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:292)
    ==5695==    by 0x40D47F: newnvpair (config.c:164)
    ==5695==    by 0x40D7A9: process (config.c:244)
    ==5695==    by 0x40D90B: readParamFile (config.c:276)
    ==5695==    by 0x407973: getCSdcList (CSdcList.c:351)
    ==5695==    by 0x40DC5F: main (main.c:48)
    ==5695== 
    ==5695== Invalid read of size 1
    ==5695==    at 0x406AD3: CIcp_SetUsedIOs (CIcp.c:160)
    ==5695==    by 0x40A9E2: LoadParams (CSdcList.c:1163)
    ==5695==    by 0x407B84: getCSdcList (CSdcList.c:396)
    ==5695==    by 0x40DC5F: main (main.c:48)
    ==5695==  Address 0x5b86e0c is 0 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
    ==5695==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:292)
    ==5695==    by 0x40D47F: newnvpair (config.c:164)
    ==5695==    by 0x40D7A9: process (config.c:244)
    ==5695==    by 0x40D90B: readParamFile (config.c:276)
    ==5695==    by 0x407973: getCSdcList (CSdcList.c:351)
    ==5695==    by 0x40DC5F: main (main.c:48)
    ==5695==
```

I'm pulling my hear out in desperation...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which line of the `CIcp_SetUsedIOs` function is line number 160? Are you calling the function with correct arguments (remember that indexes are zero-based, i.e. goes from zero to size minus one)? If `len` is wrong then you might index outside of `str`. In your case, the memory allocate (for `str` supposedly) is `12`, so `len` must be at most `12` (though that should include space for the terminating `'\0'` character).

Comment: I see no use for `str` at all in the setup to `CIcp_SetusedIOs`, so something tells me the string your acquiring from `getvalue()` isn't as long as you suspect. if it is a terminated string then you should be using the terminator as the stopping point; not assuming `MAX_STR_LEN`.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that all of your "name" strings are exactly of size `MAX_STR_LEN`.  But if you look at your loop in `CIcp_SetUsedIOs`, you always loop over `MAX_STR_LEN` elements.  You should probably check for `'\0'` and break out of the loop.  Either that, or pass the correct length of the string into the function.

Comment: You are totally right! I have been coding around the clock for the past three months on this project to get it done. Now I am starting to go blind on my own code. I definitely need some sleep... And thank you so much for taking your time! It means the world to me.

Answer (score -2):

```
'this' is a reserved word (in C++) so best to not use it.

what is a 'pnv'? Is it some kind of struct. 
Perhaps you could include the struct definition 

what is ASSERT();? I know of an assert( something is true);

what is a Cicp?

perhaps the code should initialize usedInputs and usedOutputs  to zero 
before setting bits

hopefully, usedInputs and usedOutputs are larger than a single char 
(though the call to function ctob() may mean char to binary?
because a single char only has 8 bits.  and the offsets allowed are
0 ... 8  I.E. a 9 bit range.

this code snippet: (0x01 << (str[i] - '0'));
since the shift value (str[i] - '0') can be 8, and the working size of the shifted value
is only 0x01 (a single byte), some the shifts can result in a bit of a problem.

the function loadparams() will not cleanly compile 
because the function indicates a return value of type int, 
but no such return statement is in the function

There is plenty of other problems with the code, but the valgrind message
is probably about ...inputs |= and ...outputs |= statements
```